# While installing hadoop, when I run start-dfs.sh command it shows 'no such file or directory found'

Tags: bash, hadoop

[image]

```
[root@nn1 hadoop-2.9.0]# ./sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [nn1]
nn1: namenode running as process 2707. Stop it first.
nn1: datanode running as process 2859. Stop it first.
dn1: bash: line 0: cd: /home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0: No such file or directory
dn1: bash: /home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: No such file or directory
dn2: bash: line 0: cd: /home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0: No such file or directory
dn2: bash: /home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 3052. Stop it first.
[root@nn1 hadoop-2.9.0]#
```

For reference:
Master:
Hostname= nn1
Username= user1

Slave1:
Hostname=dn1
username=slave1

slave2:
Hostname=dn2
username=slave2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running the commands as the root user, not `user1`, where it's looking for the files.

And you really should not run any component of Hadoop as root anyways

It also says your processes are running, so it's not clear why you're trying to start them again